# How to setup a simple deathmatch in Battlefield4?

Tags: battlefield-4

I've got a bunch of friends who want to play a simple everyone against everyone deathmatch on Battlefield between ourselves.

We want to be able to choose the maps we play and only play again each other. There'd probably be around 8 of us at any one time.

Is this possible, or do we need to setup/ rent our own server?

If it is possible how do we go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can not create your own private server as per your need. For this purpose you'll have to rent a server. Cost of renting server as per the duration for which they need to be rented. After renting the server, you can customize it to your heart's desire.

[Rental Info](http://help.ea.com/in/article/battlefield-4-server-rental-info/)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Gameranand said, for Battlefield 4 the way to do this properly is to rent a server.

One way to go about this otherwise is to find an empty server (assuming you're able to use a server browser like on PC, I'm not sure what platform you're on), and just use that for you guys. Other people might join in at some point but that'll happen on public servers. You could try filtering empty servers with a small number of players allowed to reduce that chance.

Comment: There is a server browser on console and I think it's the same as PC.